# datepart year AND quarter in one column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, parsing, time

I need to parse out the year and quarter from the `Date` column. My data looks like this:

```
Feb 1, 2019
Feb 2, 2019
```

Desired output is:

```
2019, 1
2019, 1
```

I have tried:

```
QUARTER(`Date`)
```

But this only gives me back the quarter `1`. Can't find a way to include both year and the quarter. Thank you!

Comment: Why isn't your date simply stored using the proper type, `date`?  You should fix your data.

Comment: The data type IS `Date` but how would I grab the year and quarter? I need to group the other columns by the quarter. I can't change the source of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CONCAT` to show both year and quarter

```
SELECT CONCAT(YEAR("2017-06-15"), ", ", QUARTER("2017-06-15"));
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If your data looks like:

```
Feb 1, 2019
Feb 2, 2019
```

You should first standardize it to a standard format:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Feb 1, 2019','%b %e,%Y') as date;
```

Then you can get the year and quarter using @aRvi's answer